# How to add images to chart labels with vue-chartjs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I want to add flag icons under the country code labels but am completely stuck.

[Image of the chart with my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11uUF.png)

The images are named `BR.svg, FR.svg and MX.svg` and are located under `@/assets/icons/flags/`

I am using `vue@2.6.12` and `vue-chartjs@3.5.1` in my project. This is my **Chart.vue component**:

```
<script>
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  extends: Bar,
  data: () => ({
    chartdata: {
      labels: ['BR', 'FR', 'MX'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Lorem ipsum',
          backgroundColor: '#AF78D2',
          data: [39, 30, 30],
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      tooltips: {
        "enabled": false
      },
      scales : {
        xAxes : [ {
            gridLines : {
                display : false
            }
        } ],
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            suggestedMin: 0,
            suggestedMax: 40,
            stepSize: 5,
          }
        }]
      },
      "hover": {
        "animationDuration": 0
      },
      "animation": {
        "duration": 1,
        "onComplete": function() {
          var chartInstance = this.chart,
          ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

          ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
          ctx.textAlign = 'center';
          ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

          this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
            var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
            meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
              var data = dataset.data[index] + '%';
              ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
            });
          });
        }
      },
    }
  }),
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options)
  }
}
</script>
```

This runnable code below is the closest to a solution I have come by hours of searching. But it still won't do the trick because I don't know how to integrate it with what I have.

```js
const labels = ['Red Vans', 'Blue Vans', 'Green Vans', 'Gray Vans'];
const images = ['https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RAv2.png', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq5DA.png', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KRtW.png', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLyVi.png'];
const values = [48, 56, 33, 44];

new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: "bar",
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {      
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx; 
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
      xAxis.ticks.forEach((value, index) => {  
        var x = xAxis.getPixelForTick(index);      
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = images[index],
        ctx.drawImage(image, x - 12, yAxis.bottom + 10);
      });      
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: values,
      backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'lightgray']
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },    
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{ 
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          padding: 30
        }   
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```

When I have added the plugin code into my own code I get an error message saying 'plugins' is already defined in props, but I can't manage to use it somehow.

Anyone who knows how to implement this afterDraw plugin into my code? I appreciate any input.

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the mounted of your vue component you can call the addPlugin (has to be done before the renderChart method) like this:

```
this.addPlugin({
  id: 'image-label',
  afterDraw: (chart) => {      
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx; 
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
      xAxis.ticks.forEach((value, index) => {  
        var x = xAxis.getPixelForTick(index);      
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = images[index],
        ctx.drawImage(image, x - 12, yAxis.bottom + 10);
      });      
    }
})
```

Documentation: https://vue-chartjs.org/api/#addplugin

Comment: It is a workaround but not able to set the size of the image itself.
Another issue is, it won't support svg which has color in the path or css styles in the svg.

Any thoughts that can solve this issue? Looks like ChartJS is not supporting adding images as icon along with the tick text labels and have flexibility of arrange the image icon yet?

Comment: You will never be able to use css since it's a canvas and not html, also chart.js is limited by the addimage canvas api

Answer (score 1):

It works in ChartJS version 4.0.1. data needs to return 'plugins':

```
data() {
    return {
        plugins: [{
            afterDraw: chart => {
                    const ctx = chart.ctx;
                    const xAxis = chart.scales['x'];
                    const yAxis = chart.scales['y'];
                    xAxis.ticks.forEach((value, index) => {
                        let x = xAxis.getPixelForTick(index);
                        ctx.drawImage(images[index], x - 12, yAxis.bottom + 10)
                    });
                }
        }],
        data: {...
```

Please note that ctx should be chart.ctx and NOT chart.chart.ctx.. Similarly, it should be chart.scales['x'] and NOT chart.scales['x-axis-0'].

After you return plugins, this needs to be referenced in your Bar component like so..

```
<Bar :data="data" :options="options" :plugins="plugins"/>
```

Comment: Nice one, did help me a lot. Thank you. Wonder if there is a way to bring it into the chart options.